# How do I update the avatar that does for each of my accounts in the Gmail app?

Tags: gmail

A few days ago, I added an image to each of my gmail and Google apps accounts. The new images display fine in the account dropdown menus on the web. But only one of my accounts displays the new image in the gmail app. I cannot think of anything I did differently with that one account. I've closed and restarted the app, rebooted my phone. What am I missing?